# Trace and eigenvalue decomposition, and convexity of a matrix function.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, trace

I am studying the convexity of a function with trace. It is described as follows:

$f(X)=tr(X^{-1})$ on $\boldsymbol{dom} ~f=\boldsymbol{S}_{++}^n$

Define $g(t)=f(Z+tV)$, where $Z\succ 0$ and $V \in \boldsymbol{S}^n$.

$g(t)= tr((Z+tV)^{-1}) \\
     ~~~~~~= tr(Z^{-1}(I+tZ^{-1/2}VZ^{-1/2})^{-1}) \\
     ~~~~~~= tr(Z^{-1}Q(I+t\Lambda)^{-1}Q^T) \\
     ~~~~~~= tr(Q^TZ^{-1}Q(I+t\Lambda)^{-1})) \\
     ~~~~~~= \sum_{i=1}^{n}(Q^TZ^{-1}Q)_{ii}(1+t\lambda_i)^{-1},$

where $Z^{-1/2}VZ^{-1/2}=Q\Lambda Q^T$ by eigenvalue decomposition.

In this derivation, I cannot understand why the last line $tr(Q^TZ^{-1}Q(I+t\Lambda)^{-1})) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(Q^TZ^{-1}Q)_{ii}(1+t\lambda_i)^{-1}$ holds.
For me, it looks like the result that the trace of a matrix is a sum of its eigenvalues.

Is $Q^TZ^{-1}Q$ a diagonal matrix? If it is true how can we show that it is true. If it is not, how come the last line hold?

I am stuck to this problem for days, your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't matter if $Q^TZ^{-1}Q$ is diagonal or not, only that $(I+t\Lambda)^{-1}$ is. In general, if $D$ is diagonal, then ${\rm tr}(AD)=\sum a_{ii}d_i$ by inspection (the diagonal entries of $AD$ are just $a_{ii}d_i$s after all).

Comment: @runway44 Thank you

Answer (score 1):

By the definition of the trace, and then using the fact that $I+t\Lambda$ is diagonal, we get
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\text{tr}\left(Q^TZ^{-1}Q(I+t\Lambda)\right)&=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\left(Q^TZ^{-1}Q\right)_{ij}\left(I+t\Lambda\right)_{ji}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\left(Q^TZ^{-1}Q\right)_{ij}\delta_{ji}\left(1+t\lambda_i\right)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(Q^TZ^{-1}Q\right)_{ii}\left(1+t\lambda_i\right)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you very much.